# Is it possible to assign return of function value to a type generic?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to assign the boolean result of a function to a type generic. **Is this possible**? I have the following schema:

```js
interface FormalWebFieldProps {
  name: string
  id: string
  onChange: (e: FormalTextFieldEvent) => void
}

interface FormalNativeFieldProps {
  onChangeText: (text: string) => void
}

type FormalFieldProps<IsNative> = {
  disabled: boolean
  value: any
  error?: string
} & (IsNative extends true ? FormalNativeFieldProps : FormalWebFieldProps)
```

If I just pass `<true>` or `<false>` to the generic type of `FormalFieldProps`, it works:

```
const getWebFieldProps = (): FormalFieldProps<false> => {
  return {
    id: 'field id',
    name: 'field name',
    disabled: false,
    value: 'foo',
    error: 'error',
    onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value)
  }
}

const getNativeFieldProps = (): FormalFieldProps<true> => {
  return {
    disabled: false,
    value: 'foo',
    error: 'error',
    onChangeText: text => console.log(text)
  }
}
```

However, as this validation is dynamic and happens on runtime, I don't know if it is possible to assign the return of that function to the generic type, something like this:

```js
const isNative = () => false

const getDynamicFieldProps = (): FormalFieldProps<bool = isNative()> => {
  const extra = !isNative() ? {
    id: 'field id',
    name: 'field name',
    onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value)
  } : {
    onChangeText: text => console.log(text)
  }

  return {
    disabled: false,
    value: 'foo',
    error: 'error',
    ...extra
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript only does type checking at compile time. It can only infer return types from types, not values

Comment: @Richard yes I assume it may happen. Any suggested solution?

Comment: A union type like `const getDynamicFieldProps = (): FormalFieldProps<boolean> => ...` doesn't work for you?  I think I need to see more use cases here before I can suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare your flag as normal declarartion like 
isNegative = false;

and with help of ternary operator you can execute your block of code

like

```
isNegative? {
    id: 'field id',
    name: 'field name',
    disabled: false,
    value: 'foo',
    error: 'error',
    onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value)
  }: {
    disabled: false,
    value: 'foo',
    error: 'error',
    onChangeText: text => console.log(text)
  }
```

this is not a perfect code but you will get some idea.

Comment: But that will break my typing.